# Automatic wireless scan on startup/login and resume

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager

I'm running 12.04 on my MacBook Pro 5,5, and my Wi-Fi is working fine, but I'm having problems getting it to scan automatically at startup time.

On first login I get a notification that I'm disconnected, and no networks are listed in the Network Manager tray widget, even though `Enable Wireless` is ticked.

If I go to the terminal and do a manual scan, Network Manager kicks in after a second or two, populates the list and connects automatically to a saved network if available.

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 s
```

I've run the following commands immediately after startup for diagnosing the situation

```
$ iwconfig
$ sudo lshw -C network
$ sudo lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

(output [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6044003/))

I'm not an expert, but as far as I can tell the driver is loaded and everything is working, but Network Manager just doesn't start a scan without a kick in the behind. I've spent a lot of time searching around, but I can't seem to find anyone with the same issue. Anyone know how I can resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, this was probably a problem with [Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager), and not driver related. I installed [Wicd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) as a workaround and removed Network Manager, and now everything is working perfectly.

If I try to reinstall Network Manager and remove wicd again, I will post the results here, in case the problem was a corrupt config file or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

From ubuntuforums, this is related to a bug on Network-Manager, valid workaround in here:

Change the last part in /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager

```
from
  thaw|resume)
    resume_nm

to
  thaw|resume)
  resume_nm
  sleep 2 && iwlist eth1 scanning &
```

This will force a network rescan on every resume.

Kudos to mu3en from
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/274405/comments/74

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

It  will open a text editor and then

paste these lines

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Then restart your system to apply the changes. From now on wards even you have suspended your system , after wake up it will again reconnect.

Credit: [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840116&page=3)

Note: make sure that you dont have too many saved connections.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately this had no effect.

Comment: look at the Forums link in my answer. its a years research thread.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this was a dead end.